# takeLatestHelper has been cancelled in redux-saga-effects

Tags: redux-saga

Here is a brief on my code before I go into issue:

I have index.js where I am putting all the watchers for my saga. And this file is importing sagas from different files. It looks something like this:

```
import {fork, call, put, takeLatest, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
import { getKpiListSaga, getDimensionsListSaga } from './chartSaga';

function* watchGetKpiList() {
  yield takeLatest(types.GET_KPI_LIST_REQUEST, getKpiListSaga);
}

function* watchGetDimensionStructure() {
  yield takeLatest(types.GET_DIMENSION_LIST_REQUEST, getDimensionsListSaga);
}

export default function* root() {
  yield [
    fork(watchGetKpiList),
    fork(watchGetDimensionStructure),
 ];
}
```

And in my chartSaga.js, I am making the respective api calls:

```
import {put, call} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { getKpiList,  getDimensionsStructureForFacts} from '../services/api';
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
import _ from 'lodash';

export function* getKpiListSaga() {
  try {
    const kpis = yield call(getKpiList);
    yield [
      put({type: types.GET_KPI_LIST_SUCCESS, kpis}),
    ];
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({type: types.GET_KPI_LIST_FAILURE, error});
  }
}
```

So the basic idea was, when my page was loading, I called an action to make a request of type `GET_KPI_LIST_REQUEST` and it used to end up in Saga and I got the results back in my reducer on success or failure. Then on selecting a KPI, I can make call for dimension related to that KPI.

This was all working fine when I was doing `import {takeLatest, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga';` and using `yield` not `yield*`. It was showing the deprecation message so I changed the import to be from effects and as per examples, yield should do the trick.

But my first call to get KPIs on page load is working fine. When I trigger the action to get dimensions, I am getting logs in console like this (it goes on for all the watchers, I am just including a snippet below):

```
takeLatestHelper has been cancelled    utils.js?1f12:206 
watchGetKpiList has been cancelled     utils.js?1f12:206 
takeLatestHelper has been cancelled    utils.js?1f12:206 
watchAuth has been cancelled              utils.js?1f12:206
```

After this point there are no api calls being made as all watchers are cancelled. Is there any change in configuration that I am missing?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: yes, this was due to some error in configuration.

Comment: @VivekVDwivedi do you mind elaborating on the config error that you had that fixed this?

Comment: @jamcreencia I don't exactly remember the exact config, but if you are facing a similar issue, please raise a question and maybe link it here.